# After formatting External Harddrive, Why do hidden OS folders $RECYCLE.BIN, System Volume Information get created

Tags: windows-8, operating-systems, virus

My antivirus ESET Nod 32 was flagging up a virus found in my C:/$Recycle.bin folder, after reinstalling fresh OS I decided to store some things on an external Harddrive and dumped to another PC.

My anti virus then noticed a folder **$RECYCLE.BIN** on my external Harddrive, I decided to format this completly on a diff machine, after doing so I ran cmd as admin and check to see if the **$RECYCLE.BIN** or **System volume Information** was present after the format, which it wasnt.

However after plugging this external Harddrive into another machine, As soon as I do this the folders **System volume information** seem to be created.

Is it possible that a virus is being stored inside this **$RECYCLE.BIN** folder and is being automatically dropped there to any external usb device attached?

Seems I might have to simultaneously reinstall both machines?

Answer (score 0):

Windows requires the system folder $RECYCLE.BIN on each disk; these store "deleted" files until the Recycle Bin (which displays all files in each $RECYCLE.BIN together) is emptied. System Volume Information is a file required by the HDD file system and cannot be viewed while the drive is mounted. Empty the Recycle Bin, and if you still get an indication of an issue from ESET Nod 32, and ESET cannot remove the malware, try free AV tools such as Malwarebytes, https://www.malwarebytes.org/, which can run a single scan, so as to not interfere with another AV.